# Logic operators in a LIKE pattern

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I use logic operators in a LIKE pattern?

Exemple:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE '%something || somethingelse%';
```

**Note 1 :** My question is for mySQL, but an overview of how other implementations of SQL treat such queries will be helpful.

**Note 2 :** If this is not possible, is there any alternatives besides using

```
WHERE bar LIKE '%something' OR bar LIKE 'somethingelse%'
```

What I want to accomlish is to be able to inject some string into the LIKE pattern and be able to return results from the database that meet that pattern.

Comment: [MySQL RLIKE/REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) and [OWASP SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) may be handy resources for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL support some base [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

```
where bar regexp ('something$|^somethingelse')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the strings into one string and then apply LIKE operator, like:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE CONCAT('%something', yourstring, 'somethingelse%');
```